# jquery treetable ajax call

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

iam newbie to jquery. I need to build tree-table. I built the main folders as below. I need to insert files under each node. I have an array of files as below **This array will be dynamic not static**. I have given the sample. how to insert these files in the nodes.

arraylist of documents to be inserted under documents:

1. mydoc.doc,
2. mylistitems.doc,
3. referlist.doc,
4. officeit.doc,
5. stlidt.doc
   [image: here]

Can this is possible using jquery?

Else suggest me another other way or plugin which can do this?